# How to use docker to create linux images per user on the same domain

Tags: networking, docker, docker-network

Here is what I would like to be able to do ( I am not even sure what to look for on the net for docs).

```
docker run --name userXXX -d ubuntu
docker run --name userYYY -d ubuntu
docker run --name userZZZ -d ubuntu
```

such that I can hand out a root login to a container@ a domain. Like:

> ssh root@userXXX.somedomain.foo
>
> ssh root@userYYY.somedomain.foo
>
> ssh root@userZZZ.somedomain.foo

Is this even possible? I am imagining that I would need to setup DNS on

> somedomain.foo

and have all the hosts on the same docker network (that seems logical enough). The problem I can't seem to figure out is the correct routing where hostname.somedomain.foo => docker container

Each container would need it's own IP
Register update the DNS record with that host/ip
the DNS needs to be one of the DNS authority for somedomain.foo that all machines on my real network know about.

Has anyone done this sort of thing?

If this question is more appropriate for superuser then let me know and I can move it

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use OpenSSH proxy in one container and use that to route to your users' containers. You could script the proxy config to add entries as you add users.

From: https://superuser.com/questions/960666/route-ssh-traffic-based-on-domain-with-haproxy

> ```
> Host  *.internal.lan
>    ProxyCommand ssh -q -A  -x proxy.example.com -W %h:%p
> ```
>
> Now, if you connect to the names listed in the Host line, your SSH
>   client will first connect to proxy.example.com (which must point to
>   your public IP address) and use it as a gateway to forward to the
>   actual machine...

Also see: [SSH ProxyCommand example: Going through one host to reach another server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/)